# Create-react-app unable to open IDE when error occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phpstorm, create-react-app, webstorm

I am using `create-react-app` and everything is working as expected. However I would like that when an error occurs it automatically opens the file in question.

I have set up the `.env.local` file as [suggested](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration).

```
BROWSER=none
REACT_EDITOR=phpstorm
```

**Error**

```
Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.


Could not open persistStore.js in the editor.
The editor process exited with an error: spawn phpstorm ENOENT.

To set up the editor integration, add something like REACT_EDITOR=atom to the .env.local file in your project folder and restart the development server.
```

Maybe this is an error with PhpStorm rather than RCA?

Comment: Are you running windows, mac or linux?

Comment: Ah of course, Linux. Mint 19

Comment: Try `pstorm` instead of `phpstorm`. Thats what the PhpStorm CLI is called.

Comment: does PhpStorm start when you run `phpstorm` in terminal? I'd suggest re-creating the command line launcher via **Tools -> Create Command line launcher** and then specifying the launcher name in `.env.local`

Comment: Interesting, I have added `/home/hutber/PhpStorm/bin` to my path, but still `pstorm` isn't there as a command in terminal. I will research :D

Comment: Nailed it guys, once pstorm was in terminal everything worked :) Please add as an answer? I also used in phpstorm `Tools > create terminal CLI`